# Make multiple socket-connections in each own thread in python, stuck after 3 connections?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures

I have a dict of objects containing username/hostinformation for connecting to a server and want each connection to be run in it's own thread, but seem to get at most 3 out of my 100 test-objects to connect properly no matter if i try to use concurrent.futures or the threading module. I understand that it has something to do with the current thread executing before the previous threads are finished, because i managed to get from only being able to connect one user to 3 users by sleeping 2 seconds between each connection, but this is of course not a working solution to handle manually, plus i noted that increasing the sleeptime to 5 or more seconds still only connected 3 users, which leds me to think maybe there is another issue than this too?

I have been playing around with wait-keyword for executor.shutdown without really understanding it but with no luck, read somewhere that the problem might be related to GIL but according to other sources this is nothing that affects what I'm trying to do, personally I have no idea at all about any way to get around that except for running multiprocessing instead of threads.

```
number_of_objs = 100

def run_(obj):
     obj.connect()

objs = {}

for i in range(number_of_objs):
     nickname = f"{nickname_prefix}_{i}"
     hostname = "server.example.com"
     port = 1234
     objs[i] = CreateObjs(nickname, hostname, port)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for k in objs.keys():
        time.sleep(2)
        executor.submit(run_, objs[k])

# Result:
# Testuser_0 successfully connected to server.example.com at port 1234
# Testuser_1 successfully connected to server.example.com at port 1234
# Testuser_2 successfully connected to server.example.com at port 1234
```

Comment: What happens if you add `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)`?

Comment: @Juha Still the same result of max 3 users connecting. I actually set max_workers=number_of_objs when i started out but have been trying to make this work and going back and forward with this so many times i forgot to put it back

Comment: Then there are more problems. Please add your `obj.run()` code. But from the description you should not be using `ThreadPoolExecutor` but either directly threads or constructs like `asyncio`.

Comment: The connect-method of the class creating the objects that are passed in to the run_ func is just a socket-connection taking parameters from the __init__ like host, port and username and then do a sock.connect(), have to get back later for the exact implementation since I don't have access to the code from my phone, but there is nothing more than the connection to the server going on there. Do you have any suggestions on how to implement this using threading-module (as i assume you mean by "directly threads"?) My experiments with that lead to the exact same result. Thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I guess correctly your intentions, `ThreadPoolExecutor` is not the right construct here. Let's first test the following non-concurrent code:

```
for k in objs.keys():
    run_(objs[k])
```

This code should make the connections sequentially, and the next one should start when the previous have ended. If you want to use `ThreadPoolExecutor`, this code should work.

What `ThreadPoolExecutor` actually does is that it runs a number of tasks concurrently, and if the number of tasks is greater than the amount of workers, the rest of the tasks are queued to wait for the previous tasks to end. The issue with GIL is that `ThreadPoolExecutor` does not function as expected if the tasks contain only computing, as they cannot be run in a true multithreaded fashion due to GIL. Now, if the tasks in `run_` start waiting for the remote server, start sending test date or something similar, `ThreadPoolExecutor` does not work as the first tasks never end.

If the wish is to start 100 parallel threads to do some I/O, this should be used:

```
for k in objs.keys():
    threading.Thread(target=run_, args=(objs[k],)).start()
```

Note: you cannot start arbitrary number of threads like this. 100 is fine, as is probably 1000, but there are practical limits to the number of active threads.

Comment: I will try this in about 7 hours when I have the code in front of me, far away from any computers atm :) and accept this answer if it end up working as expecting. However don't i have to handle joining the threads manually and do some magic to make the threads to shutdown as the mainloop stops as well (daemon=True)? This was the reason I saw using ThreadPoolExecutor as the better option as it handles the underlaying logic of the creation of the threads automatically from what i understood. But as you probably can tell I'm not too sure about the correctness of that assumption :)

Comment: I'm accepting your answer since the problem of my question was solved excellent using the threading.Thread in the for-loop. Now i however got other things to deal with regarding ssl-errors that i haven't counted for since i wrap my socket inside ssl_context and it seems to mess up things running it this way, but that's another issue indeed. Thank you very much for this working solution!